# Efficient way to rotate bitmap without OOM issue

Tags: android, bitmap

I know this is an old question. But I didn't find any proper solution for this. I want to rotate a large `bitmap`, do some processing on it and later save it to a `file`. I am using below method to rotate the `Bitmap`. But when I rotate multiple bitmaps. I get `OOM` on low end devices. I don't want to downscale the bitmap. How can I avoid that?

```
val matrix = Matrix().apply { postRotate(degrees) }
Bitmap.createBitmap(this, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true)
```

Any better solution than this?

Answer (score 0):

This is one way you can rotate your bitmap without OutOfMemory Issue.

```
Drawable getRotateDrawable(final Bitmap b, final float angle) {
    final BitmapDrawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), b) {
        @Override
        public void draw(final Canvas canvas) {
            canvas.save();
            canvas.rotate(angle, b.getWidth() / 2, b.getHeight() / 2);
            super.draw(canvas);
            canvas.restore();
        }
    };
    return drawable;
}
```

and also you can convert drawable to bitmap easily

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap();
```

Comment: this code doesn't change anything at all

Comment: this code just returns the same `bitmap` which were used for `BitmapDrawable `, unmodified

Comment: @user924 for that you will have to set the angle. 90, 145, 180, 360.

Answer (score -1):

Try Object Animator with animations

```
ObjectAnimator rotatedrawable= ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(drawable ,
                "rotation", 0f, 180f);//instade of 180 you can put any angle you want
        rotatedrawable.setDuration(100); // animation duration
        rotatedrawable.start();
```

Comment: This answer is no where related to my question.

Comment: this is way to rotate the bitmap with smooth animation.

Comment: But I want to rotate the bitmap for background processing and later save it to disk as a file.